# Reading data from Pulseoximeter via Serial Port in C++

Tags: c++, serial-port

I have a pulseoximeter and I want to read data from Serial Port. This task isn't so easy because I need to set some communications parameters. I set the baud rate, but it is not enough. I need to set the parameters from this page: https://www.tranzoa.net/~alex/blog/images/Communication%20protocol.pdf.
How can I set these parameters in C? This problem is implemented in python here: https://github.com/atbrask/CMS50Dplus. I need it in C/C++. I mention that I need it for Linux.
Now I have a simple C++ program which is able from read ordinary data from Serial port:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>


using namespace std;

char Buffer[100];
int Port_ID;

int Available() {
    int n = 0;
    int m;
    if ((m = ioctl(Port_ID, FIONREAD, &n)) < 0) {
        cout << "ioctl failed with " << m << "\r\n";
        return -1;
    }
    cout << "ioctl read " << n << "\r\n";
    return n;
}

void Receive(){
    char chr;
    int i = 0;
    memset(Buffer, '\0', strlen(Buffer));
    while (Available() > 0){

            read(Port_ID, &chr, sizeof(chr));
            Buffer[i++] = chr;
            cout << chr; 

    }
}

int InitSerialPort(string portname) {
    cout << "I'm serial comm!\r" << endl;

    Port_ID = open(portname.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
     printf("Open() PortID! %s Port ID %d\r\n", strerror(errno), Port_ID);
    return Port_ID;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    memset(Buffer, '\0', strlen(Buffer));
    int i=1, n;
    char message[50];
    Port_ID = InitSerialPort("/dev/ttyPS1");


    while(i++){
        Receive(); 
        if(strlen(Buffer) > 0){
            cout << Buffer;
            memset(Buffer, '\0', strlen(Buffer));    
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This isn't C but C++.

Comment: This is C with cout, but not C++.

Comment: `memset(Buffer, '\0', strlen(Buffer));` what will strlen(Buffer) be?

Comment: manni66 You answered to my question with an answer! So I did not get closer to the solution.